# Error - expressSessionMiddleware is not a function

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io, express-session

I'm trying to use express-socket.io-sessions to sockets with the users' sessions, but I keep getting this error when I try add the middleware. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var sharedSession = require("express-socket.io-session");

function main(req, res, server, session) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/find.html");

    var io = socket(server);

    io.use(sharedSession(session, {
        autoSave: true
    }));

}
```

All the parameters passed to the main function seemed when I console.log'd them, so I don't think it's that. Any help on why this error occurs would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what's `session`? I guess is not a function

Comment: it's JSON. I just passed in req.session which I got with express-session module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to middleware `session` into express app after that you can use the `sharedSession` middleware.

Correct way

```
var app = require('express')(),
  server  = require("http").createServer(app),
  io = require("socket.io")(server),
  session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");


// Attach session
app.use(session);

// Share session with io sockets

io.use(sharedsession(session));
```

Reference to official documentation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session